# Concurrency problem when only parts of a class are annotated with @MainActor

Tags: swift, concurrency, task, mainactor

I have set *Strict Concurrency Checking* to *Complete*, and the following code compiles without warnings in Xcode 15.0.1 and Xcode 15.1 beta 3.

When running it, it shows a concurrency problem. The `inc()` method is allowed to run on two tasks at the same time.

My questions:

- Am I correct to assume that this should not compile without a warning?
- Which part of this code is illegal? I think it's starting the `Task` in `run()`. But maybe the non-MainActor `inc()` method should not be synchronously callable from the MainActor.

```
class Counter {
    private var counter = 0

    func inc() -> Int {
        let v = counter + 1
        for _ in 0...1000 {}
        counter = v
        return v
    }

    @MainActor
    func run() {
        Task {
            while true {
                try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                let v = inc()
                print("xxx t1", v)
            }
        }
    }
}

class Experiment {
    func start() {
        Task {
            let counter = Counter()
            await counter.run()

            while true {
                try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                let v = counter.inc()
                print("xxx t2", v)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##### Update 2023-12-04:

I tested this code with the current Swift 5.10 snapshot and the line `await counter.run()` now triggers the warning "*Passing argument of non-sendable type 'Counter' into main actor-isolated context may introduce data races*"

It looks like this PR fixed it: https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/67730

Comment: Concurrency checking is performed at runtime, not at compile time, so what you are seeing is correct. Your code compiles but concurrency checking at runtime determines that there is a potential problem

Comment: The warning comes because `inc` is not bound to an actor and it is not `private` so it can be called from anywhere at any time and indeed you are doing so,  calling it from two different Tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> - Am I correct to assume that this should not compile without a warning?

I agree. I would have expected a compile-time warning. This code is not thread-safe. `Counter` is not `Sendable` and is being captured within a `@Sendable` closure.

FWIW, the behavior I experience (in Xcode 15.0.1 and 15.1 Beta 3) is as follows:

1. If I remove the `@MainActor` isolation on the `run` method, I receive the appropriate compile-time error when using the “Strict Concurrency Checking” build setting of “Complete”:

   > Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'Counter' in a '@Sendable' closure.

   The “Strict Concurrency Checking” build setting controls the compile-time warnings that you will receive. It primarily is checking that objects crossing task boundaries are `Sendable` or not. (For those unfamiliar with these issues, the WWDC 2022 video [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351/) is a good primer.)

   So this warning is correct: `Counter` is non-sendable. This code is not thread-safe.
2. But if I restore the `@MainActor` isolation of `run`, as shown in your original example, the compiler fails to produce the relevant warnings (even though `Counter` is no more thread-safe than above; it is still non-sendable).

   This having been said, you reported runtime errors. I only manifested runtime errors when I turned on Thread Sanitizer (TSAN). As an aside, this is a reason why the compile-time warnings of “Strict Concurrency Checking” are normally much better than runtime checking: Many thread-unsafe behaviors are not consistently manifested at runtime. The “Strict Concurrency Checking” can detect thread-safety mistakes that might be hard to manifest at runtime.

   But getting back to your question, it is unclear why the compiler fails to detect that `Counter` is non-sendable in the presence of the `@MainActor` isolation of only the `run` method. Isolating just this one function makes `Counter` no more thread-safe than it is without the `@MainActor` isolation. (In defense of the Swift compiler authors, all of this sendability checking code must be pretty complex.)

You went on to ask:

> - Which part of this code is illegal?

Regardless of whether `run` is isolated to the main actor or not, the problem is that this code is simply not thread-safe. `Counter` is not `Sendable`. It exposes the `inc` function which is mutating a non-isolated property, which means that while the task initiated by `run` is executing, it is possible for another thread to call `inc` in parallel. (Or, multiple threads could call `inc` simultaneously, regardless of whether `run` was ever called or not.) This code is not thread-safe.

There are a number of ways of fixing this code. We want to make `Counter` a `Sendable` type. We could isolate the whole `Counter` type to `@MainActor` (or any global actor). Or we could this `class` an `actor`, instead. Or you could add your own synchronization and mark this as `@unchecked Sendable` (but the burden for the correctness of the thread-safety now rests on your shoulders and the compiler will be unable to verify this). But, as it stands, `Counter` is not thread-safe.